# QTEST_MAIN doesn't use provided Testclass

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8, qobject, qtestlib

I want to do a performance test on threads and their interactions (e.g. shared data). To achieve this, I tried the Qt provided Tutorial for Benchmarks, which lead me to write the following code.

The Benchmark-Class:

```
class Bm : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void Benchmark_1()
    {
        bm_1 bm;
        QBENCHMARK
        {
            pool.start(&bm);         //pool is a QThreadpool
            pool.start(&bm);
            pool.waitForDone();
        }

    }
    void Benchmark_2()
    {
        bm_1 b_1; bm_2 b_2;
        QBENCHMARK
        {
            pool.start(&b_1);
            pool.start(&b_2);
            pool.waitForDone();
        }
    }
};
```

The class that contains the task for the thread:

```
class bm_1 : public QRunnable         //bm_2 looks just like bm_1
{
public:
    void test_1();
    void run()
    {
        test_1();
    }
};
```

The main-function gets replaced by a QTest-macro:

```
QTEST_MAIN(Bm)
```

QTEST_MAIN returns 0, which means, according to the Qt-documentation, there is nothing to be tested. If I now try to use the debugger, to get a glimp of what might go wrong, I get two startup-errors:

> The Gdb-process was terminated(0)

and

> During startup program exited with code 0xc0000138

**What did I do wrong?**

I need `QTest` (and not e.g. ellapsedTimer) to measure the performance without OS and adobe updater pollution. It's a company owned laptop. I checked my includes, and I even reinstalled Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my wrong doing.
The class that contained my benchmark was called `Bm`, the files it was implemented in were called `benchmar.cpp`and `benchmark.h`. Changing the name of the class to `benchmark` resolved the problem.

Why that is i have no clue and me reading the QObject 4.8 dokumentation didn't get me any further. Soo... one more quirk to live with.

Whoohey!